What does $\xi_{\mathcal{F}} -\langle \theta ,\xi_{\mathcal{F}}\rangle+\mathcal{F}$ mean?
Assume that $\omega$ is symplectic two-from on a Manifold $M$ such that $\omega =-d\theta$ where $\theta$ is a one-from on $M$. We know that for every $\mathcal{F}\in C^{\infty}(M)$, there is a vector field $\xi_{\mathcal{F}}$ on $M$ given by $\xi_{\mathcal{F}}=\omega^{\sharp}d\mathcal{F}$. I know that $\langle \theta,\xi_{\mathcal{F}}\rangle\in C^{\infty}(M)$ where $\langle \theta,\xi_{\mathcal{F}}\rangle (p):=\langle \theta_p,(\xi_{\mathcal{F}})_P\rangle$. I have two questions that I don't understand: (1) what does $\xi_{\mathcal{F}} -\langle \theta ,\xi_{\mathcal{F}}\rangle+\mathcal{F}$ mean? I mean how can we sum a vector field with a function? (2) If $M=\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with coordinates $q^i,p_i$ and with two form $\omega =dq^i \wedge dp_i$ where $\theta=p_i dq^i$. How can I compute $-i\hbar \xi_{q^i}-\langle \theta ,\xi_{q^i}\rangle $ to be $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}$?

This looks like a construction that arises in geometric quantization. If you're taking the expression to act on wavefunctions $\psi$ (which here would be represented by functions on $M$), then $\xi_\mathcal{F}$ is interpreted as an operator acting on $\psi$, while $\mathcal{F}$ just means "multiplication by $\mathcal{F}$". In other words, you should really interpret it as $\mathcal{F} \operatorname{id}_\mathcal{H}$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is your Hilbert space of wavefunctions. There's also a way of interpreting these as vector fields on a $\operatorname{U}(1)$ bundle over $M$, but I won't get into that here.
To answer your second question, with your conventions, $\xi_{q^i} = -\frac{\partial }{\partial p_i}$, and so $\langle\theta,\xi_{q^i}\rangle = \langle p_j\, dq^j,-\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}\rangle = 0$, giving the result.

Dear @user17945 Thank you very much for your explanation. Yes, my question arises from geometric quantization. I got it. You mean we are adding three operators with each other not a vector field with a function. Am I right? But $\xi_{\mathcal{F}}$ is a deriavtive from $C^{\infty}(M)$ to $C^{\infty}(M)$. How can I see it from $\mathcal{H} $ to $\mathcal{H}$? And one ore thing, why $\xi_{q^i}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}$?

The Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ will be some subset of $C^\infty(M)$ (the specific subset will depend on the polarization used). That $\xi_{q^i} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial p_i}$ follows immediately from the definition of $\xi_{\mathcal{F}}$, which can equivalently stated as $i_{\xi_\mathcal{F}}\omega = d\mathcal{F}$.

Sorry, how can we see $\mathcal{H}$ as a subset of $C^{\infty}(M)$? $\mathcal{H}$ is a set of complex functions $g:M\to \mathbb{C}$ while $C^{\infty}(M)$ is the set of real functions.

I'm being sloppy - it's some subset of complex-valued functions on $M$, as you say, but the operator is defined on some dense subset of differentiable functions.
